# How do I make manually installed fonts accessible to all applications without running `fc-cache -f`?

Tags: dpkg, fontconfig

With `dpkg` new fonts get installed and usable in no time. When I add a font manually I have to use `fc-cache -f`, which takes a lot of time to complete. How do I install fonts manually the dpkg way? How does dpkg make them accessible to all applications without running `fc-cache -f`?

Comment: What about not using `-f`? There should be no need to regenerate *everything*.

Comment: @DanielB Why does **everyone** recommend `fc-cache -f` in their tutorial on how to install a font?

Comment: dpkg is working with a source that's already been processed.  Doing it manually isn't.

Comment: Not quite true. Apparently it works either way. So they recommend the `-f` *just in case*. (To cover all imaginable cases.)

Comment: Why? It most certainly doesn’t hurt. Also, everyone does it, so it must be right. It’s essentially a [Cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How do you make fonts accessible without running `fc-cache -f`

Don't run `fc-cache -f`!

At least on my system (Arch), fonts are picked up once they are placed in a directory known to fontconfig (and the cache has been rebuilt automatically).

### `fc-cache -f` forces a rebuild of the font cache

From [the man page for fc-cache](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-fc-cache/):

> ```
> -f
>    Force re-generation of apparently up-to-date cache files, 
>    overriding the timestamp checking.
> ```

But if the font cache doesn't need updated, why would you force it to be?

You can run `fc-cache` without arguments instead. The [Arch wiki has more suggestions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fonts#Manual_installation):

> To install fonts system-wide (available for all users), move the folder to the /usr/share/fonts/ directory. [...]
>
> Then update the fontconfig font cache: **(usually unnecessary as software using the fontconfig library do this.)**
>
> ```
>   $ fc-cache
> ```

*(emphasis mine)*

### Example

I didn't have the font [Titillium Web](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Titillium+Web) installed:

[image: grep -i titi returns nothing]

So I downloaded it (permissive license, OFL!) and copied the ttf files to `/usr/share/fonts/TTF`. I was going to run `fc-cache` (sans `-f`) to see if the cache needed updated, but first I reran `fc-list | grep -i titi`:

[image: oh there they (the fonts) are]

<sup>The gif pauses for a while before looping as I was a bit surprised that the font cache had been updated</sup>

And they had already been cached! They were available to applications, as expected. No need for `fc-cache`, and definitely no need to force it with `-f`.